# Hokuyo laser configuration

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am currently using URG-04LX hokuyo laser and there is one problem that every time I power on this laser I need to reconfigure it all over again. Whenever I "ls -l /dev/ttyACM0", the feedback will always be `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Oct 17 15:10 /dev/ttyACM0`

I was thinking could I possibly save the configuration(**sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0**) or is there any launch code that would possibly do this job?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91721/hokuyo-laser-configuration/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the more fancy udev solution that we use (needs the hokuyo_node package) and /etc/ros/run.sh:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Hokuyo Data Flex for USB", ATTRS{product}=="URG-Series USB Driver", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout", PROGRAM=="/etc/ros/run.sh hokuyo_node getID %N q", SYMLINK+="sensors/hokuyo_%c"
```

Besides access rights this uses the getID util in hokuyo_node to provide device symlinks as /dev/sensors/hokuyo_SERIAL to enable identifying specific sensors neverminds which ttyACM they land at.

/etc/ros/run.sh enables ROS

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/ros/setup.sh 
rosrun $@
```

/etc/ros/setup.sh is a symlink to the setup.sh in /opt/ros/DISTRO/setup.sh

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-16**:
What is the different between your solution and the solution provided by @Tones ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-17**:
This one also provides device ids based on the serial number. Also it sets access rights for any user (other), not only dialout, but you can configure that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend adding your username to the group `dialout`:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

---

Originally posted by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) with karma: 635 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-16**:
How does this make a difference? What is suppose to happen after I enter this command?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-16**:
That is what you were asking for. It gives your user permanent access rights to this device so you don't have to "chmod" any more.

**Comment by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) on 2013-10-16**:
The idea behind the command is to add your user to the group, which has read/write access for `/dev/ttyACM0` by default instead of setting read/write access for all users every time again.

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-10-22**:
I can confirm that this has been THE  way to solve access right issues for many sensors over here. It should be the preferred (simplest) solution for any /dev/tty* access issues.